# Missing styles for item in React Native Side Menu (should indicate active route in React Native Navigator)

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm working on an app with a [Side Menu](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-side-menu) and a [Navigator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#navigator). In the side menu there are menu-items which let's you navigate (using Navigator), and the menu-items also get styled to indicate which one is active.

When first going to a new route with [navigator.push()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#push) and then going back with [navigator.pop()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#pop), the menu-item corresponding to the *previously* active route (which is now inactive) does not get *either* of the **styles** to show that it is either *inactive* or *active*. The style of the menu item (`RouteMenuItem` in the full example below) is as follows

```
style={[
    { padding: 15, borderColor: 'firebrick', borderWidth: 1 },
    (isActive
        ? {backgroundColor: 'green'}
        : {opacity: 0.5}
    )
]}
```

**How is it possible that neither `{backgroundColor: 'green'}` nor `{opacity: 0.5}` gets applied?**

The image below shows how the bug looks on Android: "Route ONE" is selected, however, the menu item for "Route TWO" does not have `opacity: 0.5` as it should (it should be half transparent like the 3rd menu item).

[image: react-native-navigator-side-menu-style-bug.png]

---

Below is the full code for a minimal example to reproduce the bug. The component hierarchy is like this:

```
<Navigator renderScene={() => <SideMenu><View /></SideMenu>} />
```

PS: We use StyleSheet.create() in our code, but in the example below I've just defined the styles inline. It does not seem to make any difference.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableHighlight, Navigator, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import SideMenu from 'react-native-side-menu';

/***************
/**   Routes   **/
/****************/
const ROUTES = {
    ONE: () => ({ title: 'Route ONE' }),
    TWO: () => ({ title: 'Route TWO' }),
    THREE: () => ({ title: 'Route THREE' }),
};

/**************/
/**   Main   **/
/**************/
export default class Main extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Navigator
                style={{flex: 1}}
                initialRouteStack={[
                    ROUTES.ONE(),
                ]}
                renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
                    <Scene route={route} navigator={navigator} />
                }
            />
        );
    }
}

/***************/
/**   Scene   **/
/***************/
class Scene extends React.Component {
    state = {
        menuIsOpen: false,
    }

    openMenu = () => {
        this.setState({ menuIsOpen: true });
    }

    onMenuOpenChanged = (menuIsOpen) => {
        if (this.state.menuIsOpen !== menuIsOpen) {
            this.setState({ menuIsOpen });
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {route, navigator} = this.props;

        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <SideMenu
                    menu={
                        <Menu
                            route={route}
                            navigator={navigator}
                        />
                    }
                    menuPosition="right"
                    bounceBackOnOverdraw={false}
                    onChange={this.onMenuOpenChanged}
                    isOpen={this.state.menuIsOpen}
                    openMenuOffset={Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.75}
                    disableGestures={false}
                >
                    <Screen route={route} navigator={navigator} openMenu={this.openMenu} menuIsOpen={this.state.menuIsOpen} />
                </SideMenu>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

/**************/
/**   Menu   **/
/**************/
class Menu extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {route, navigator} = this.props;

        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'coral', paddingTop: 25 }}>
                <Text>Currently at {route.title}</Text>
                <RouteMenuItem forRoute={ROUTES.ONE()} route={route} navigator={navigator} />
                <RouteMenuItem forRoute={ROUTES.TWO()} route={route} navigator={navigator} />
                <RouteMenuItem forRoute={ROUTES.THREE()} route={route} navigator={navigator} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const RouteMenuItem = ({forRoute, route, navigator}) => (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigator.push(forRoute)}>
        <Text style={[ { padding: 15, borderColor: 'firebrick', borderWidth: 1 }, (forRoute.title === route.title ? {backgroundColor: 'green'} : {opacity: 0.5}) ]}>
            Go to {forRoute.title} ({(forRoute.title === route.title ? 'current route' : 'NOT CURRENT ROUTE')})
        </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
);

/*****************************/
/**   Screen, inside Menu   **/
/*****************************/
class Screen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {route, navigator, openMenu, menuIsOpen} = this.props;

        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <View style={{  flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', backgroundColor: 'peachpuff', paddingTop: 25 }}>
                    <HeaderButton onPress={navigator.pop}>Back</HeaderButton>
                    <HeaderButton onPress={openMenu}>Menu</HeaderButton>
                </View>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                    <Text style={{ margin: 50, fontSize: 50 }}>
                        {route.title}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const HeaderButton = ({onPress, children}) => (
    <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="green" onPress={onPress}>
        <Text style={{ padding: 10, borderColor: 'firebrick', borderWidth: 1 }}>
            {children}
        </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
);
```

Comment: Be careful with pop since the components are stacked and don't get unmounted, so your component might be on its previous state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs becauase children of TouchableHighlight gets default opacity (1) after the TouchableHighlight is pressed. As that is a more specific problem I've asked a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693073/child-of-touchablehighlight-loses-opacity-styling-on-press).

In this case the bug appears when going back to a previous route, because the menu item in that instance of the `Menu` was pressed (moving us to a new route before we could spot the bug).