# Child of TouchableHighlight loses opacity styling on press

Tags: react-native, touchablehighlight

When a child of a [TouchableHighlight](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight.html#touchablehighlight) has an opacity, its opacity disappears (is set to 1) after the TouchableHighlight is pressed.

Running example here: https://rnplay.org/apps/c0NIjQ

Minimal example:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {}}>
    <Text style={{ opacity: 0.5 }}>
        Press me!
    </Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Is there a way to mend this, or is it a bug in React Native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TouchableOpacity](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html) works as I would have expected for TouchableHighlight ([live code sample](https://rnplay.org/apps/AWeAGQ)), so using TouchableOpacity could be a workaround. *Note*, however, that TouchableOpacity does not have an underlay which appears when active, so whatever you render underneath is what will "shine through" on press. Thus, it's not a perfect substitute for TouchableHighlight.

I'm not sure whether the behavior of TouchableHighlight is intended, some sort of a tradeoff or actually a bug, but looking at the code you can clearly see how it differs from TouchableOpacity in this regard:

- [TouchableHighlight always sets the child's opacity to 1 when it goes inactive.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/c92ad5f6ae74c1d398c7cd93d5c4c50da0ca0430/Libraries/Components/Touchable/TouchableHighlight.js#L228)
- [TouchableOpacity sets the child's opacity to `childStyles.opacity` if it is set, otherwise 1, when it goes inactive.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/c92ad5f6ae74c1d398c7cd93d5c4c50da0ca0430/Libraries/Components/Touchable/TouchableOpacity.js#L160)

Answer (score 0):

You could work around it by implementing the `onPressOut` method of `TouchableHighlight`, and binding your opacity to a state property.

```
constructor (props) {
  this.state = {opacity: 0.5}
}

render () {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight 
      onPressOut={() => this.setState({opacity: 0.5})}
      opacity={this.state.opacity}
    >
      ....
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
```

Not ideal I agree.

Comment: Good idea, but it does not seem to work: https://rnplay.org/apps/DxQVAA

Comment: Even when delaying the re-render until the TouchableHighlight animation is done does not reset the opacity: https://rnplay.org/apps/VBa3mg :(